# Rethinkdb: Chain getAll & between

Tags: rethinkdb

I get `RqlRuntimeError: Expected type TABLE_SLICE but found SELECTION:` error when chaining `getAll` and `between` methods.

r.db('mydb').table('logs')
  .getAll('1', {index: 'userId'})
  .between(r.time(2015, 5, 1, 'Z'), r.time(2015, 5, 4, 'Z'), {index: 'createdAt'})

Is there a way to use `index(es)` when querying for data that belongs to `userId=1` and where `createdAt` is between dates? As I understand `filter` does not use indexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use two indexes like that, but you can create a compound index:

```
r.table('logs').indexCreate('compound', function(row) {
  return [row('userId'), row('createdAt')];
})
r.table('logs').between([1, firstTime], [1, secondTime], {index: 'compound'})
```

Comment: Ow I see. I didn't know I can use arrays. I also noticed that column sequence is important. Thx!